Would employing a random number seed that changed over time make a safer random number in Solidity
I know Solidity does not have true random number functionality and the possibility that  miners could game the usual random number generation process people employ.  I know about obtaining values off chain with Chainlink VRF.
If I had a Lottery contract would it be more difficult for miners to game the system if the random number seed is a moving target. Let's say I start out with a seed number in the contract's constructor and then modify that number with every ticket sold. Something like:
seed = seed ^ uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender, block.timestamp + block.difficulty)));

Would a moving target seed value in a private variable make it harder to cheat?
